# How to integrate conference submission templates with Overleaf?

Tags: templates, overleaf, acm

I completed writing my paper using IEEEtran and now I need to modify it to the style required by ACM. They have provided a template to be used with Latex (https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template), however, I don't understand how to use it. In addition, since I'm using Overleaf, I need to know how to integrate the template with it

Comment: you could unpack the zip file locally and then upload acmart.cls into your project but you probably do not need to do anything, `acmart.cls` is already installed in texlive so available in overleaf

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you for the information. Can you suggest how to use it? Would this work - \documentclass[conference]{acmart}

Comment: well yes,  `\documentclass{acmart}` the specific conference may dictate specific options that should be used. there are many example documents in the zip file that you referenced

Comment: That works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`acmart` is in texlive so already installed at Overleaf.

You can start

```
\documentclass{acmart}
```

the referenced zip file has many sample documents showing different options, normally the conference or journal using this class will provide specific instructions saying which options to use.